# PHP set minimum 4 digits in a number logic

Tags: php, regex, number-formatting

I am new to PHP and I am trying to set minimum 4 digit numbers in a variable and create a memberid.

```
$memberidVal = ABC0123;
$numMemberVal = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $memberidVal);
if (strlen($numMemberVal) == 3) {
    $numMemberVal = 0 . $numMemberVal;
} elseif (strlen($numMemberVal) == 2) {
    $numMemberVal = 00 . $numMemberVal;
} elseif (strlen($numMemberVal) == 1) {
    $numMemberVal = 000 . $numMemberVal;
}
$newMemberId = "ABC" . ($numMemberVal + 1);
echo ($newMemberId);
```

No matter what I do, I always get ABC124 in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newMemberId = "ABC" . ($numMemberVal + 1);
```

The above line is doing the following:

1. Taking the number string `0123` and adding the decimal `1` to it which gives you `124` thanks to [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)
2. Then it is prepending "ABC" because you tell it to

If you want to enforce the leading zero use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
$memberidVal = ABC0123;
$numMemberVal = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $memberidVal);
$newMemberId = "ABC" . str_pad(($numMemberVal + 1), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Or add `1` before you prepend your zero:

```
$memberidVal = ABC0123;
$numMemberVal = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $memberidVal);
$numMemberVal++;
if (strlen($numMemberVal) == 3) {
    $numMemberVal = 0 . $numMemberVal;
} elseif (strlen($numMemberVal) == 2) {
    $numMemberVal = 00 . $numMemberVal;
} elseif (strlen($numMemberVal) == 1) {
    $numMemberVal = 000 . $numMemberVal;
}
$newMemberId = "ABC" . $numMemberVal;
echo ($newMemberId);
```

Or use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$memberidVal = ABC0123;
$numMemberVal = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $memberidVal);
$newMemberId = sprintf('%s%04d', 'ABC', ($numMemberVal + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks John. That makes sense. What would happen if the length of number reaches more then 4? Will below example with number 4 has to be changed in future?

$newMemberId = "ABC" . str_pad(($numMemberVal + 1), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

Comment: I think I answered my own question. I did follow your sprintf() example and if the variable string has length 4 and above, it does not append zero in the front. I did test with ABC12345 + 1 with sprintf() example, and it returned me ABC12347. :)